# Ruby modules and extend self

Tags: ruby, module, class-method, instance-methods

In what sort of situation is the code:

```
module M
   extend self
   def greet
    puts "hello"
   end

end
```

more beneficial to use over say something like:

```
module M
   def self.greet
    puts "hello"
   end
end
```

In the top, one is an instance method being extended, and the latter is just a class method, but when calling either method, you'd have to M.greet , right?  I was just curious if anyone could shed some light on when to use one code over the other.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first example is typically a way people achieve the functionality of `module_function` (when they do not know the existence of this method).

A `module_function` is both an instance method and a class method. In your second code example the method is just a class method.

Comment: Oh, that's a cool method.  That way you can select which methods to give the functionality to in case you don't want to give it to all of them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It would be possible to do this with your first example, but not your second:

```
include M
greet
```

Answer (score 4):

A module can be used as a namespace by writing module methods, and a module's instance methods can be mixed into another object.

The *self-extending* module concept allows a module to be used in both ways; either as a stand-alone namespace or as a mixin. Consider this module:

```
module M
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end
class C
  include M
end
```

It has an instance method and can be mixed in to another object. It does not have a module method and cannot, therefore be used as a namespace:

```
puts M::bar # => undefined method `bar' for M:Module
puts C.bar  # => this is bar
```

But, a module is an just an object of class `Module`, as we can demonstrate

```
puts M.class   # => Module
```

This means that we can do something crazy. We can mix a module into itself so that its methods become both instance and module methods.

```
module M
  extend self
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end
puts M::bar # => this is bar
puts C.bar  # => this is bar
```